# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)

Tags: arduino-ide

I am trying to connect MFRC522 using nodeMCU and send a simple code to scan the tags but the IDE brings the following error:

```
Multiple libraries were found for "MFRC522.h"
 Used: /home/georgewayne/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries/MFRC522
 Not used: /home/georgewayne/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries/rfid-master
 Not used: /home/georgewayne/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

What do I do to rectify this error?

Comment: This mate over here seems to fix his bug by just reviewing his code: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=660724.0

But, apparently there is a bug in the ArduinoIDE. Try to use Platform.IO(platformio.org/), it has a "better" debugger, (it's a little bit hard to install tho), this may help you.

Comment: More complete output may help.  If you haven't already, turn on verbose for compiling in File/Preferences.   In and of itself, the `Multiple libraries were found` thing is not an error.  It's just warning you that it found multiple and telling you which one it chose.  If it chose the wrong one, then *that* might result in an actual compiler error that isn't shown.